# Getting Error code 3 for file transfer plugin cordova for upload image

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

Trying to upload image with cordova file transfer plugin with following code snippet.

```
var params =  {
    token: credentials.token
}
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = 'round';
options.fileName = 'round.jpg';
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};
options.params = params;
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(croppedImageURL, encodeURI(globals.nodeAppBase + 'v1/users/upload-user-picture'), function(){
    console.log("Successfully updated Round Image");
}, function (err) {
    console.log('There was an error uploading the media. Please try again later. Error: ' , err);
}, options, true);
```

But i am getting error:

> {"code":3,"source":"file:///data/user/0/com.app.package/68-image.jpg","target":"https://api.server.com/v1/users/upload-user-picture","http_status":null,"body":null,"exception":"Chain
>   validation failed"}

I tried till now:

1. Add connection params in headers of options:

> options.headers = {   Connection: "close" };

2.Add true in as last param of Upload Function.

Still getting error as above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind to check:

1. `<access origin="https://api.server.com" />` or similar in config.xml.
2. Make sure your SSL certificate chain on your server is valid. e.g. Not self-signed.

Answer (score 0):

Set Android SDK Version in `config.xml` to `27` worked for me using `cordova-android@7.1.4`

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />
```

Notice, that if you update `cordova-android` to >= 7.0.0 you are dropping support for any android versions older than `5.0.0`. See [here](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html) for more details.